# What does 'Language neutral' mean with regard to MAKELANGID?

Tags: windows, winapi, internationalization, localization

The docs for [MAKELANGID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373908(VS.85).aspx) specify that `MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL)` Means 'Language neutral'.

This seems to be English on my machine (tried it with `FormatMessage`), but what does it mean in general? Is it guarenteed to be English?

Thanks!

Comment: It means "applies equally to all languages".

Answer (score 2):

I would *expect* that this means that the strings associated with the lang id are not specific to any language - which could be useful to know for a localisation team.  "%1 + %2 = %3" would be an example of one such string.

Answer (score 2):

with sublanguage = SUBLANG_DEFAULT this would be the user's default language.
https://web.archive.org/web/20100704043524/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534732(VS.85).aspx

Here's a note on the sublanguage identifier - https://web.archive.org/web/20100728153356/http://wiki.winehq.org/SublangNeutral.

Note that MAKELANGID creates a language identifier for you from the primary language and sublanguage identifier - it does "not" get the default language, or anything like that.

Comment: All the links are 404

Comment: @totaam - i've replaced the dead links with web.archive links. cheers! The "answer" though is actually the first line (user's default language)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not "gauranteed to be English."  It "is" whatever you place into it at that point (English, in your case).  But it means that it should not serve as a (language) satellite assembly (except maybe as a fallback).