# What is the Language neutral, User default LANGID, and System default LANGID?

Tags: c++, winapi, localization

From MSDN about the [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

> If you pass in zero, `FormatMessage` looks for a message for `LANGIDs` in
>   the following order:
>
> - *Language neutral*
> - Thread `LANGID`, based on the thread's locale value
> - *User default* `LANGID`, based on the user's default locale value
> - *System default* `LANGID`, based on the system default locale value
> - US English

But zero is *Language neutral* already, because the value of *Language neutral* is 0...

```
LCID lang = MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL); // 0
```

What is the *Language neutral*? Is it the same for any computer? If "yes" then is it `en-US`?

Also what is the *System default* `LANGID`? Is it the same like on the screen?

[image]

Also what is the *User default* `LANGID`? What distinction between these three localizations? Where their values are stored in the Windows OS settings?

Comment: related/possible duplicate: [What does 'Language neutral' mean with regard to MAKELANGID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234736/what-does-language-neutral-mean-with-regard-to-makelangid)

Comment: I don't see the clear ansewer on my question in your link. Zero (i.e. 0) is the same like `LCID lang = MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL);` I.e. zero variant is the `Language neutral`. What distinction between these three localizations is? Where their values are stored?

Comment: Opps. Sorry.  I was actually looking at a link from that answer to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534732(VS.85).aspx) which has: *Type: LANGID
Optional. Sixteen-bit value that specifies the language to use. The default value is LANG_NEUTRAL, which is the user's default language.*

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN documentation for FormatMessage could be easier to understand if it said *language-neutral* instead of *Language neutral*. Windows MUI resources can be language-specific or language-neutral (you can learn more about this topic [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319070(v=vs.85).aspx)). Calling FormatMessage with `dwLanguageId=0` tells Windows to try to load a string with the given `dwMessageID` from the language-neutral resources. If the string does not exist in the language-neutral resources Windows will try to load it from language-specific resources, using the documented order of LANGIDs (thread default, user default, system default, 1033). This is a bit unusual because the process default LANGID is not considered.

The *User default* LANGID is what you get back from calling  [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137(v=vs.85).aspx). You can change it in the Control Panel (for Windows 8.1: Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language). [GetSystemDefaultUILanguage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318124(v=vs.85).aspx) returns the *System default* LANGID. I would expect that you can change it on the screen that you posted, but I am not sure if the upper or the lower button is the right one. I am afraid I don't know where these settings are stored.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, **Jenszcz**. I learn it now. `GetUserDefaultUILanguage` and `GetSystemDefaultUILanguage` always return `1049` for my computer, even if I switch the settings which I pointed on my screen before to English (USA) and reload my computer.

Comment: @AndreyBushman, you may need to use the upper button on the screen that you posted to change the _system default_ locale (sorry, I can't read Cyrillic properly). I would try myself, but I can't restart my machine at the moment... . Possibly you should change the _user default_ language first: [this article] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374098(v=vs.85).aspx) has some more info on system default and user default languages. Unfortunately it does not have a Russian translation that would help you locate the right place in the control panel. :-(

Answer (score 0):

According to leaked Windows XP source code (`NT/base/ntos/rtl/ldrrsrc.c`):

```cpp
// If search path includes a language id, then attempt to
// match the following language ids in this order:
//
//   (0)  use given language id
//   (1)  use primary language of given language id
//   (2)  use id 0  (neutral resource)
//   (3)  use thread language id for console app
//
// If the PRIMARY language id is ZERO, then ALSO attempt to
// match the following language ids in this order:
//
//   (4)  use user UI language
//   (5)  use lang id of TEB for windows app if it is different from user locale
//   (6)  use UI lang from exe resource
//   (7)  use primary UI lang from exe resource
//   (8)  use Install Language
//   (9)  use lang id from user's locale id
//   (10)  use primary language of user's locale id
//   (11) use lang id from system default locale id
//   (12) use lang id of system default locale id
//   (13) use primary language of system default locale id
//   (14) use US English lang id
//   (15) use any lang id that matches requested info
```